# phpqrcode image not recognized as an active url

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, eps

I made a PHP script that takes severall URLs from a database and outputs QrCodes using the phpQrCode Library.

Qr codes are output in an eps file and printed on handouts by our printing services.

This much is working fine, but some of the QR codes when read on my phone take me to the page directly, but some only give methe URL of the page as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The OP was able to find the solution to his own problem.  It was:

> My users have left a space in the beginning of the string when pasting the URL so the library is doing just what it is supposed to, I will be using some ltrim and rtrim to fix this.

Comment: just use trim() instead ))